# Google Cloud Datastore Index not found even if it is set

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have a kind named 'audit' and has many properties however, I need to index only certain properties and in a specific order since I mostly query:

```
select DISTINCT ON (traceId) * from audit where tenantId='123'
```

When I try to run this in the GCP console it throws an error:
`GQL Query error: Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query.`

I also tried running this from a node js application that uses [@google-cloud/datastore package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/datastore), and datastore throws error:

```
9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: audit
  properties:
  - name: tenantId
  - name: traceId
```

The index.yaml is created using terraforms and the contents are:

```
indexes:
- kind: "audit"
  properties:
  - name: "tenantId"
  - name: "traceId"
# AUTOGENERATED
# This index.yaml is automatically updated whenever the Cloud Datastore
# emulator detects that a new type of query is run. If you want to manage the
# index.yaml file manually, remove the "# AUTOGENERATED" marker line above.
# If you want to manage some indexes manually, move them above the marker line.
```

**With this index.yaml file the local datastore emulator works as expected.**

**In the GCP console, I see the index being set and is in serving status.**

Comment: How is this related to Terraform?

Comment: @MarkoE We have added the datastore index using terraforms. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/website/docs/r/datastore_index.html.markdown

Comment: But this issue is not related to Terraform per se?

Comment: I looked at my locally generated indexes and none of them have the ```kind``` or ```properties``` in quotes. Try removing the quotes in yours i.e. make it ```audit``` instead of ```"audit"```; same thing for the properties. Redeploy your ```index.yaml``` file and make sure it is set to serving status. See if that solves your problem

Comment: @NoCommandLine It works with the quotes also. I have tested it and it works well without any issue.

Comment: @SHRUTHIBHARADWAJ Can you share your Datastore entity screenshot? Also make sure you are using correct spelling for the properties in the query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have additional **quotes**,  `"` around your Datastore property names in the index.yaml file.

```
indexes:

- kind: Cat
  properties:
  - name: name
  - name: age
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/configuring-datastore-indexes-with-index-yaml#about_indexyaml) on correct syntax.

On the Google Provider Terraform side, there is a ~> [Warning](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/website/docs/r/datastore_index.html.markdown#google_datastore_index) mentioned, make sure to follow it to create a compatible database type. Refer [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/website/docs/r/app_engine_application.html.markdown#google_app_engine_application) for more details on compatibility settings.